# Split a string by comma(,) and add the objects to a collection

Tags: vba, excel

I have a requirement where I have a large string.

For Example: `abc,def,ghi`

I would want to split these strings and put them in a collection.

Required Output:

```
ExampleCollection
abc
def
ghi
```

How to do this in VBA.

Comment: Split with split() to get a string array then loop over it adding to the collection, there is no way to do it directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim s As String, c As Collection
    Dim arr

    s = "abc,def,mbs"
    arr = Split(s, ",")
    Set c = New Collection

    For Each a In arr
        c.Add a
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks !! This helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this.

```
Sub SplitAll()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xRg1 As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim xAddress As String
Dim xUpdate As Boolean
Dim xRet As Variant
On Error Resume Next
xAddress = Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select a range", , xAddress, , , , , 8)
Set xRg = Application.Intersect(xRg, xRg.Worksheet.UsedRange)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If xRg.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "You can't select multiple columns", , "Kutools for Excel"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    Set xRg1 = Application.InputBox("Split to (single cell):", "Kutools for Excel", , , , , , 8)
    Set xRg1 = xRg1.Range("A1")
    If xRg1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each xCell In xRg
            xRet = Split(xCell.Value, ",")
            xRg1.Worksheet.Range(xRg1.Offset(I, 0), xRg1.Offset(I + UBound(xRet, 1), 0)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(xRet)
            I = I + UBound(xRet, 1) + 1
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
End Sub
```

See the link below for all info.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3341-excel-split-comma-separated-values.html